# Count number of rows in which value occurs in any column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sample Data:

[image]

Desired result:

```
Name       Number Handled
Bill       1
Erica      1
James      2
Jimmy      1
John       1
Kory       1
```

Setup:

Column W is "Incident Number", Column X is "Created by", Column Y is "Resolved By", and Column Z is "Updated By". The same person can create, resolve and update or can be multiple people. The boss is asking for each person in the team, how many tickets are they touching each day. So if "James" is opened, resolved, and updated ticket 22, he did one ticket. If James opened ticket 22 but Tony resolved it, they each touched ticket 22 so both get credit. Same with Updated. Could be same person, or 3 different. For each tech I need a formula to find the total number of tickets they touched, regardless of how many actions they did on the ticket.

Comment: Sample data would definitely help. Not sure what you want in your output column. Do you want all the unique names? A count of unique names?

Comment: So setup:   Column A is "incident number"  column B is "Created by"  Column C is "resolved by"  and Column D is " updated by"   The same person can create, resolve and update or can be multiple people.   The boss is asking for each person in the team, how many tickets are they touching each day.   So if "James" is opened, resolved, and updated ticket 22, he did one ticket.   If James opened ticket 22 but Tony resolved it, they each touched ticket 22 so both get credit.   Same with Updated.   Could be same person, or 3 Different.    I have a table of Techs that can be used to compare to.

Comment: I know it sounds complicated, I have tried several IF functions, and COUNTIF functions but nothing is quite getting me the result.    I can use adjacent column's to step it toward that result but not have been able to get that result.  It may just be too complex for an excel formula.   I have a SUMPRODUCT formula to tell me how many repeat names appear in each row of 3 column's already built. It is comparing against my table of tech's.   =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(X31:Z31,Summary!$A$2:$a$19)) So basically it counts how many valid tech names exist on each row. INC can be opened and updated externally

Comment: Image added, sorry did not catch the image description.    So in the image you can see 4 ticket numbers.   INC22 James created, resolved and updated so he gets credit for 1.    23 John created it but Jimmy resolved and updated it so both get credit. 24 Kory created it and updated it so he gets credit as Erica is not a tech, shes the customer.   25   James created, Bill Resolved, John updated so all 3 would get credit for that ticket.     As I stated there is a table containing valid tech names on another sheet.   Does that help?   I'm stuck on this.

Comment: Ok, so is there a 5th and 6th column for Name and Total?

Comment: Kevin, it is on another page but yes.

Comment: I added a picture of the results page.    So it already calculates how many Tickets each tech created, resolved, updated.   However I need a total that is accurate for tickets touched because right now the total is just adding the 3 values together.  which as seen in my example is not accurate because the same tech can do all 3 which totaling counts as 3 tickets.

Comment: If you've got 365 you could use `=IFERROR(ROWS(FILTER($X$2:$Z$5,($X$2:$X$5=$A2)+($Y$2:$Y$5=$A2)+($Z$2:$Z$5=$A2))),0)`.  Where `$A2` is pointed at your list of names.

Comment: @JaymeH Does my answer help?

Comment: Kevin, unfortunately it did not seem to work.

Comment: Darren, the amount in column x,y,z changes day to day.   The actual sheet has 80 rows of data today.   Could be 50 tomorrow, so formula needs to look at everything.   I am going to use what you posted and see if I can get it working.    It may put me on the right track.    I'm not sure why my manager's manager needs this data.   Justify our work I guess.

Comment: @Kevin  That worked!   Thank you!

Comment: @JaymeH Check my edited answer. Also, if you put an @ before peoples names in a comment, they will get a notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another column (I used AA) that concatenates the three columns. You'll need to replace "Sheet1" with whatever the sheet name is

```
=CONCATENATE(",",Sheet1!X1,",",Sheet1!Y1,",",Sheet1!Z1,",")
```

Then your formula is a simple countif with search

```
=COUNTIF(AA:AA,"*,"&A2&",*")
```

Comment: Note that this approach will run into trouble if you have a "Sam" and "Samantha" for instance, since Sam will get credit for all of Samantha's work too.  If that's going to be an issue for you, I've provided a formula that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following formulas to get the result (assuming your names are in column A of another sheet.  Use the first formula if calculation speed isn't an issue and your number of rows varies a lot.  Use the second formula for faster calculation if you can be confident that the number of rows won't go above some number.  Just replace 1000 with your own number.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN((Sheet1!$X:$X=$A2)+(Sheet1!$Y:$Y=$A2)+(Sheet1!$Z:$Z=$A2)))
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN((Sheet1!$X$2:$X$1000=$A2)+(Sheet1!$Y$2:$Y$1000=$A2)+(Sheet1!$Z$2:$Z$1000=$A2)))
```

Comment: You can improve removing the row references.  I.E. instead of $X$2:$X$8 just do $X:$X

Comment: @Kevin Good point.  Doing this will slow down the calculations, which may be an issue for larger workbooks.